# Align cout format as table's columns

Tags: c++, string, format

I'm pretty sure this is a simple question in regards to formatting but here's what I want to accomplish:

I want to output data onto the screen using `cout`.  I want to output this in the form of a table format.  What I mean by this is the columns and rows should be properly aligned.  Example:

```
Test                 1
Test2                2
Iamlongverylongblah  2
Etc                  1
```

I am only concerned with the individual line so my line to output now (not working) is

`cout << var1 << "\t\t" << var2 << endl;`

Which gives me something like:

```
Test                 1
Test2                  2
Iamlongverylongblah         2
Etc                  1
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  cout << setw(21) << left << "Test"    << 1 << endl;
  cout << setw(21) << left << "Test2"   << 2 << endl;
  cout << setw(21) << left << "Iamlongverylongblah"     << 2 << endl;
  cout << setw(21) << left << "Etc"     << 1 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add "<< left". This is required if you want left-aligned fixed fields.

Comment: std::left is not reset on every formatted output, you only need it once.  (The stream's width *is* reset.)

Answer (score 10):

I advise using [Boost Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/format/index.html). Use something like this:

```
cout << format("%|1$30| %2%") % var1 % var2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You must find the length of the longest string in the first column.  Then you need to output each string in the first column in a field with the length being that of that longest string.  This necessarily means you can't write anything until you've read each and every string.

Comment: Isn't there a easier way? Using setw or something.

Comment: >Isn't there a easier way?
Not unless you can predict the future.

>Using setw or something.
Yes, setw is one way to "output each string in the first column in a field with the length being that of that longest string."

Comment: Most formatted output I've seen doesn't bother to find the max size of a field and if it overruns a decent value, oh well, but the formatting looks a little weird when it does.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `std::format`

with alignment syntax `"{:<30} | {:<30}\n"`. This enables you to format your text using an aligment with a specific width.

To format a table you would append to a std:string table_rows and format the elements with alignment and width, like so:

`table_rows += format("{:<32} | {:<30}\n", str_col_1, str_col_2);`

For debugging some fill-in chars might come handy, which you can set like this: `format("{:*<32} | {:+<30}\n" ...` .

In case you really need to work with dynamic width, then determine the longest "str_col_1" and use it as another parameter to format:

`std::format("{:<{}}", "left aligned", 30);`

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fmt/format.h>

int main()
{
    std::string table_rows;
    std::string str_col_1[] = {"Name", "Age", "Gender", "City"};
    std::string str_col_2[] = {"John", "25", "Male", "New York"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        table_rows += fmt::format("{:<10} | {:<15}\n", str_col_1[i], str_col_2[i]);
    }

    std::cout << table_rows << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Name       | John           
Age        | 25             
Gender     | Male           
City       | New York
```

Referencing:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter
https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with

```
string str = "somthing";
printf ("%10s",str);
printf ("%10s\n",str);
printf ("%10s",str);
printf ("%10s\n",str);
```

Comment: Surely he already knows that with "printf" it can be done. He is specifically asking for "cout".

Comment: How do you know what he (OP) knows? OP never said he tried printf, nor that he wants just cout based answer (-(-1)).

Comment: `cout` is in the title and they wrote: "I want to output data onto the screen using `cout`"