# Output aligned columns

Tags: c++, cout

I am learning C++. I have a problem formatting the output of my program. I would like to print there columns perfectly aligned but so far I cannot do it, here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    employee employees[5];

    employees[0].setEmployee("Stone", 35.75, 053);
    employees[1].setEmployee("Rubble", 12, 163);
    employees[2].setEmployee("Flintstone", 15.75, 97);
    employees[3].setEmployee("Pebble", 10.25, 104);
    employees[4].setEmployee("Rockwall", 22.75, 15);

    printEmployees(employees, 5);

    return 0;
}

// print the employees in my array
void printEmployees(employee employees[], int number)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<number; i++) {
        employees[i].printEmployee();// this is the method that give me problems
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

in the class employee I have the print employee method:

```
void printEmployee() const
{
    cout << fixed;
    cout << surname << setw(10) << empNumber << "\t" << setw(4) << hourlyRate << "\n";
}
```

Problem is when I print "flinstones" line the emp number and rate are not lined up. something like this happens:

```
Stone        43 35.750000
Rubble       163    12.000000
Flintstone        97    15.750000
Pebble       104    10.250000
Rockwall        15  22.750000
```

Can anybody help me? (I tried to add tabs.. but it didn't help)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275484/cout-formatting

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the class employee of print employee method:
Use this line to print.

```
cout << setw(20) << left << surname << setw(10) << left << empNumber << setw(4) << hourlyRate << endl;
```

You forgot to add "`<< left`". This is required if you want left aligned.

Hope it ll useful.

Comment: Yeah I guess it was the left thing that I was missing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 9):

You need to set a width *before* you print out the name to get other things to line up after that. Something on this general order:

```
cout << left << setw(15) << surname 
     << setw(10) << empNumber << "\t" 
     << setw(4) << hourlyRate << "\n";
```

I'd (at least normally) avoid trying to mix fixed-width fields with tabs as well. It's generally easier to just use widths to align things.

Answer (score 0):

C++ supports a number of features that could be used for
formatting the output. These features include:

1. ios class functions and flags
2. Manipulators

Using ios class function, we can use width() method of ios class, like this:

[image: img]

Or we can use manipulators to format the output. To print the above output we can use:

```
cout << right << setw(5) << 543 << right << setw(5) << 12 << endl;
```

It will allocate 5 character width for first argument (here it is 543) and format it by padding it on the right. Similarly it will allocate a 5 character field for second argument.