# Aligning (formatting) output in C++ // Multiple variables in a single line

Tags: c++, formatting, output, cout

I'm trying to display (using `cout`) the coordinates of a set of points, and i wish to get something like this:

```
Point 1: (    2.10 ,     3.95)
Point 2: ( -511.00 ,   108.66)
Point 3: (    0.00 , -1000.33)
```

I've tried to use `setw()`, `std::left`, `std::left` and `std::internal`, but i only get things like:

```
Point 1: (    2.10 , 3.95)
Point 2: (    -511.00, 108.66)
Point 3: (    0.00, -1000.33)
```

This is an example of my output line:

```
cout << "Point: " << i;
cout << setw(8) << left << " (" << p[i][0] << ", " << p[i][1] << ")" << endl;
```

Can someone provide guidance on how can I achieve my desired output?
Thanks.

Comment: Try using `setw` immediately before the variable you want to affect, and repeat before each variable that should be fixed-width.

Comment: This question can easily be answered by reading the first part of a good reference book or tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674097/output-aligned-columns

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks a lot for your collaboration, I'm trying it right now.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I can't use your answer as you don't suggest any "good" reference books or tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to call `setw` immediately before inserting each numeric value, because most overloads of `operator<<()` clear the width setting.

So you probably want

```
std::cout << " (" << std::setw(8) << std::right << p[i][0]
          << ", " << std::setw(8) << std::right << p[i][1] << ")" << std::endl;
```