# alternative way of cout alignment

Tags: c++

I've been trying to figure out how to align my output using the cout in my compiler. I referred to several question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674097/output-aligned-columns) but it didnt help me.

The above link provide help using the `<<right or <<left`

However, after using either of the 2 it doesn't really align my output as shown in my image link below

[image]

As you can see, d13's price only has 3 digits while the others have 4 which caused my misalignment

Therefore, this is what i do in order to align the prices

```
cout << "D13"
     << setw(7)
     << setfill(' ')
     << " "
     << d13p
     << right
     << setw(3)
     << setfill(' ')
     << " "
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Is there any alternative way of a cout alignment?

Comment: Please create a screenshot in an accepted image format, and post the image inline.

Comment: Or just paste the output in a code block - it's monospace, so we will see the alignment issues just like in the screenshot.

Comment: Why the `<< " "` if you're using `setw()` already? If you really think you need these put them before `setw()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i need to use <<" " in order to ensure spaces in between the output

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan As Joachim said in his answer, use `setw()` for the fields, not to generate the spaces.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what could be another alternative way to format and arrange my output ?

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan Why do you think you need an alternative? `setw()` `left` and `right` work perfectly fine, if used correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for *an alternative*, just use `setw()` correctly. Easiest way to maintain is to use it for **all** of your fields:

```
cout << setfill(' ') // use once
     // Field 'Durian'
     << setw(8)
     << left
     << "D13"

     << ' ' // Column spacing
     // Field 'Price'
     << setw(5)
     << right
     << d13p

     << ' ' // Column spacing
     // Field 'Qty'
     << setw(3)
     << right
     << d13qty

     ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `setw` manipulator for the *spaces*, set it for the *values*

Something like

```
std::cout << "D13" << std::right << std::setw(11) << d13p << ...;
```

The spacing between the "columns" will be automatic.

[Simple demo with output in neat columns](http://ideone.com/4CRSJc)

Comment: OP wants to guarantee at least one space, so `std::cout << "D13" << ' '<< std::right << std::setw(10) << ...`

Comment: @MooingDuck And that's no problem with setting enough width, just add one to the field width and you're guaranteed to have an extra space.

Comment: _@JoachimPileborg_ @MooingDuck's comment has a point  For sake of maintainability it might make sense to break everything down to column fields and spaces between. There's at least no difference performance or otherwise efficiency wise.