# Using various format specifiers of c in c++

Tags: c++, format-specifiers

As in c we can use various format specifiers like

- **%nd** where n is a number, to print the number with a total of atleast n space covered
- **%0nd** same as above, except pre-padding with 0's   **" %05d ",3 => 00003**
- **%.nf** to set precision of n after decimal
- etc ....

So is there any way to use these with **std::cout** ?

I got some negative feedback in a recent course (c++ for c programmers) in coursera, for using **printf** instead of **cout** because i wanted to some formatting :(

Comment: Read about the [stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Comment: Maybe this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275484/cout-formatting

Comment: Something that might be the best of both worlds at times is Boost.Format. It's typesafe and much more compact than C++'s `<iomanip>`. Not likely useful in a course perhaps, but good to know about.

Comment: @chris Regretfully, it uses `%` as the insertion operator, as well as the format specifier, which results in practically unreadable code.  (Python tried this, and finally switched to using a member function of `string`, `format`.  The solution doesn't work as well in C++, because it requires a type safe varargs facility.)  And of course, even with `boost::format`, you'd want to use manipulators, to keep the formatting information separate from the text (something essential for maintenance).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `%nd` `%0nd`, C++ equivalents are `std::setw()` and `std::setfill()`.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::endl
#include <iomanip>      // std::setfill, std::setw

int main () {
  std::cout << std::setfill ('x') << std::setw (10);
  std::cout << 77 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output: `xxxxxxxx77`

`%.nf` can be replaced by `std::setprecision` and `std::fixed`,

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::fixed, std::scientific

int main () {
    double a = 3.1415926534;
    double b = 2006.0;
    double c = 1.0e-10;

    std::cout.precision(5);

    std::cout << "fixed:\n" << std::fixed;
    std::cout << a << '\n' << b << '\n' << c << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
fixed:
3.14159
2006.00000
0.00000
```

Comment: Yes, but you never really want to use any of them (except maybe `std::setw`) in production code (although they're handy for quick tests).  Also: there are a number of manipulators defined in `<ios>` and `<istream>` as well.  `<iomanip>` only defines those which take an argument.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I know that. I think that the manipulators above are enough for the OP's use.

Comment: One of his requirements was `%.nf`.  For that, you'd need `std::fixed`, which is in `<ios>`.  (Note that `std::setiosflags` cannot be used to set the base, the floating point format or the adjustment fields.)

Comment: @JamesKanze and user1920482, is cout<<setprecision() is equivalent to cout.setprecision() ??  Is there any difference?

Comment: @HarendraSingh It's `cout << setprecision(n)`, but `cout.precision(n)`.  The first is a manipulator (which I don't think I've ever used); the second a member function (which the manipulator will call), usually used in a custom manipulator, as part of a larger set of formatting options.  The member functions of `ostream` (or more often its base classes) and the standard manipulators are set very low level, physical information; in any large application, you will want to specify the _logical_ element.

Answer (score 7):

[C++ stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io)s don't use format-specifiers like C's `printf()`-type functions; they use [`manipulators`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

#### For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


int main()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << 42.0 << std::endl;
}
```

#### Output:

```
42.000000
```

[See it run!](http://ideone.com/bBLSuR)

Answer (score 6):

The usual solution in C++ is to defined manipulators which state
what your trying to format, rather than to hack physical values
directly at the point of output.  (One possible exception is the
width, where `std::setw` may be useful directly.)  Thus, for
example, when actually outputting something, you won't specify
zero padding, or fixed, with 2 decimals, but something like:

```
std::cout << temperature(2) << theTemporature;
```

where `temperature` would be something like:

```
class temperature
{
    int myMinWidth;
public:
    temperature( int minWidth )
        : myMinWidth( minWidth )
    {
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, temperature const& manip )
    {
        dest.setf( std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield );
        dest.precision( 2 );
        dest.width( myMinWidth );
        return dest;
    }
};
```

For the list of format modifications available, see the
specification of `std::ios_base`, and the fields of
`std::ios_base::fmtflags`.

If you're doing a lot of output, you might want to modify this
to restore the original format flags at the end of the full
expression.  (All of the format information except the width is
sticky, so forcing fixed format here leaves you with fixed
format for the rest of the program, which isn't necessarily what
you want.)  I use the following as base class for all of my
manipulators:

```
class StateSavingManip
{
public:
    void operator()( std::ios& stream ) const;
protected:
    StateSavingManip() : myStream( nullptr ) {}
    ~StateSavingManip();
private:
    virtual void setState( std::ios& stream ) const = 0;
private:
    mutable std::ios* myStream;
    mutable std::ios::fmtflags mySavedFlags;
    mutable int mySavedPrec;
    mutable char mySavedFill;
};
```

implementation:

```
namespace {
int getXAlloc() ;
int ourXAlloc = getXAlloc() + 1 ;

int
getXAlloc()
{
    if ( ourXAlloc == 0 ) {
        ourXAlloc = std::ios::xalloc() + 1 ;
        assert( ourXAlloc != 0 ) ;
    }
    return ourXAlloc - 1 ;
}
}

StateSavingManip::~StateSavingManip()
{
    if ( myStream != nullptr ) {
        myStream->flags( mySavedFlags ) ;
        myStream->precision( mySavedPrec ) ;
        myStream->fill( mySavedFill ) ;
        myStream->pword( getXAlloc() ) = NULL ;
    }
}

void
StateSavingManip::operator()( 
    std::ios&           stream ) const
{
    void*&              backptr = stream.pword( getXAlloc() ) ;
    if ( backptr == nullptr ) {
        backptr      = const_cast< StateSavingManip* >( this ) ;
        myStream     = &stream ;
        mySavedFlags = stream.flags() ;
        mySavedPrec  = stream.precision() ;
        mySavedFill  = stream.fill() ;
    }
    setState( stream ) ;
}
```

Note the use of the `pword` field to ensure that only the first
temporary manipulator restores the format; the destructors will
be called in the reverse order of construction, but the order of
construction will typically not be specified if you have more
than one such manipulator in an expression.

Finally: not everything is possible using this technique: if you
want to systematically append a degree sign to the temperature,
there's no way of doing so.  In this case, you need to define
a class Temperature, and overload the `<<` operator for it; this
allows everything imaginable (much more than you could ever
achieve with `printf` style formatting).

Answer (score 2):

C++ stream manipulators ([iomanip](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)) were specifically designed to support all of the standard c format specifiers operations, just with an entirely different interface. E.g. `setfill` and `setw` for the width and fill part of `%02d`.

Of course if you really need format strings (e.g. because it makes i18n easier for you), then you should have a look at `boost::format`, and if you have C++11 then you can easily write  small variadic template wrapper around it, to make the format call look more like printf.

Whatever you do, please try to not use printf. It is not typesafe, and not extendible for  output operations on user defined types.

Comment: `boost::format` really doesn't by you much.  It's poor choice of the insertion operator (`%`) results in fairly unreadable code.  It may be a good choice if you need the positional argument handling (the equivalent of X/Open's extension to `printf` formatting), but for the format itself, you'll want to use manipulators, since for maintenance reasons, you don't want the physical format mixed up in the text string.

Answer (score 1):

There are stream manipulators, if you need them.
 But I think you want to know this thing:
 `cout` is smarter than `printf()`.
Say you have:

```
int x = 34;
cout<<x;
```

Now the compiler will call:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, int arg);
```

for you. And this function will print the output in console( since in your case `stream` is `cout`). The standard library supplies overloads for this `<<` operator for all fundamental datatype available.

Comment: First, this function does _not_ print the output in console: it outputs to where ever `stream` goes (which could be a file, a string, or just about anything else). Second, this doesn't address what seems to be his question: how to modify the format used for the output.  And third, you really should mention that you can overload `<<` for your own types; this is really one of the most important issues.