# Declaring a random pointer and storing numbers on the next 5 addresses, but its not outputting the numbers from on the addresses, what is the problem?

Tags: c++

I wanted to see if it was possible to store numbers on the addresses that come after variable a's address.

```
 //declariing a  variable
int a=0;
// declaring a pointer
int *str;
//assigning 'a' adress to the pointer
str =&a;

//storing numbers on next 5 adrdess starting from 'a' adress
for(int i =0; i<5;i++){
   cout<<"input number %i: ";
cin>>*(str+i);
}

//outputing numbers stored on next 5 addresses starting from 'a'

for(int j =0; j<5;j++)
cout<<"content: "<<*(str+j);
```

but when i try to store numbers on the next 2 addresses it works fine:

```
  //declariing a  variable
int a=0;
// declaring a pointer
int *str;
//assigning 'a' adress to the pointer
str =&a;

//storing numbers on next 2 adrdess starting from 'a' adress
//for(int i =0; i<5;i++){
   cout<<"input number %1: ";
   cin>>*(str+1);
   cout<<"input number %2: ";
cin>>*(str+2);
//}

 //outputing numbers stored on next 2 addresses starting from 'a'

//for(int j =0; j<5;j++)
cout<<"content1: "<<*(str+1);
cout<<"content2: "<<*(str+2);
```

Comment: `cin>>*(str+i);` Undefined Behaviour is Undefined. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: C++ doesn't have any kind of bounds checking for pointers. Or arrays.

Comment: The problem is that the shown code [makes demons fly out of everyone noses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon). That's why the program is "not outputing the numbers".

Comment: notwithstanding UB cited by others, If `a` was an array:  `int a[5] = {0};`, then the expression `str = &a[0];` would allow the follow-on code to populate the elements of the array via eg `str[0], str[1]...`.  as `str` is now pointing to memory owned by your process.

Comment: *I wanted to see if it was possible to store numbers on the addresses that come after variable a's address.* -- I wanted to see if this rope that is rated to hold 500 pounds can hold 1000 pounds.  Hey it didn't break for me, but it did when my friend tried it with his rope.  That's the territory you are in when you try things like this.

Comment: What happens if the compiler decides to use a register for variable `'a'`?  Not all variables are stored in addressable memory; the could be stored in registers or elsewhere.

Comment: Another consideration:  the compiler places the variable `'a'` at the end of memory.  Thus there is no more memory after `'a'`.  Similarly, the `'a'` variable could be placed on the stack, thus you are overwriting stack values if you go past the address of `'a'`.

Comment: @JOWMIND *but when i try to store numbers on the next 2 addresses it works fine:* -- I guess you didn't understand my rope analogy.  There is no guarantee what will happen, the program may work, crash, work today, crash tomorrow, work for 10 years and then crash, work on 1000 computers but crash on computer 1001, etc.  So it makes little sense to try and figure out why broken code doesn't show signs of breakage.  It is broken because you are writing into memory you did not explicitly reserve for your use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to write to memory that you do not own.

Repeated from comment, if `a` was an array: `int a[5] = {0};`, then the expression `str = &a[0];` would point to memory your process owns, allowing the follow-on code to populate the elements of the array via eg `str[0], str[1]...`.

I am a new to C++, so forgive the C approach, but see the following commented code describing the differences, i.e. to create array space, then use a pointer to point to the space...

```
int main(void)//minimum signature of main includes void
{
    int a[5] = {0};//array of 5 int
    // declaring a pointer
    int *str;//int pointer
    char in;
    char buf[20];
    //assigning 'a' address to the pointer
    str =&a[0];// point pointer to array

    //storing numbers on next 5 address starting from 'a' address
    for(int i =0; i<5;i++)
    {
        //cout<<"input number %i: ";//see comment below code
        cout<<"input number: ";
        cin >> in;
        a[i] = in - '0';//use char to convert input to digit value
    }

    //outputting numbers stored on next 5 addresses starting from 'a'

    for(int j =0; j<5;j++)
    {
        sprintf(buf, "content is: %d\n", a[j]);//using stdio.h
        cout <<  buf;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

An aside:
Some of your `stdout` streaming calls, eg.

```
cout<<"input number %i: ";
```

appear to use format specifiers.

`C++` `streams` don't use format-specifiers like C's printf()-type functions; they use manipulators.  [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539608/using-various-format-specifiers-of-c-in-c)