# Tab '\t' has inconsistent spacing

Tags: c++, format

I am using `\t` to space out my output, but it produces inconsistent spaces.

For example, the following code produces

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Terms\tResults\tet(%)\tea(%)\n";
    return 0;
}
```

> `Terms   Results et(%)   ea(%)`

*Note the difference in space*

Why is this so?

Comment: That's weird, if I put a space bewtween `'\t'` and `Result`, the tab between Results and et is longer....

Comment: @Rakete1111, I've tried this but the output is ugly.

Comment: If you don't want variable spacing, don't use tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word "tab" is a prefix from "table" or "tabulate". The purpose of tabs is to generate vertical alignment, such as arrangement of text into table columns, or achieving consistent leading indentation for each paragraph. The purpose of tabs isn't to generate equal horizontal spacing. How much space is generated by a tab depends on how close it is to the next tab stop. That's why you're seeing the **"difference in space"**.

The tab character, and its interpretation on terminal devices, originates with the Tab key on typewriters. The Tab key on a typewriter triggers the motion of the carriage, which comes to rest at at the next tab stop. Typewriter tab stops are configurable by the typist by moving mechanical sliders.

On character display devices, the ASCII TAB character works similarly: it advances to the next tab position. Tab stops are commonly every eight characters. (On some terminals they are configurable via menus in the firmware, or even escape sequences that the host computer can generate).

Modern word processing programs still imitate the typewriter tab stop sliders as wedge-shaped elements that can be added to a "ruler" and moved around.

Try this:

```
std::cout << "Terms\tResults\tet(%)\tea(%)\n";
std<<cout << "a\tb\t\tc\n"
```

You should see tabular alignment:

```
Terms   Results et(%)   ea(%)
a       b               c
```

Note we had to use two tabs after `b` because the `Results et ...` field overflowed a tab position.

Ideally, we should move the tab stops around based on the width requirements of the columns in our table. But moving tabs stops around is quite non-portable. For this reason, using tabs for vertical alignment in the output of computer programs is basically not very feasible; columnar formatting is better achieved using spaces.  A good formatting function can provide for arbitrary field widths, with left, center or right alignment within a field.

Answer (score 8):

Tab ends each 8th column.

```
v       v       v       v       v
1234567812345678123456781234567812345678
Terms   Results et(%)   ea(%)
```

Comment: How to make equal spaces between strings then?

Comment: Is this true, every 8 spaces?  I thought tabs could be set a 2, 3, or 4 spaces, such as editors allow.

Comment: @CroCo, just use equal number of spaces?

Comment: The default is normally 8; you can use other tools (such as editors, or the `pr` command) to change the width of tab stops.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the tab size is dependent on the tool viewing the text

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, it is defenitely configurable in a text editor and webbrowser, but I'm not sure if it is configurable in windows console. At least 8 is default and I've never seen the other value. Output is real tab character, not spaces, the console shows it in such way.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that tabs can't be used for consistent alignment of columns, especially with variable-width fonts.

Comment: For a program printing to stdout (if that's a terminal), the tab settings depend on your tty settings. The default is usually 8 columns. If you view the output in an editor, the editor will probably override the tty settings and use its own internal settings (`:set tabstop=...` in vim, for example).

Comment: @CroCo To achieve portable formatting use `std::setw()` etc. See also [cout Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275484/cout-formatting)